# Postfix relayhost not working

Tags: email, postfix

I have a simple goal: I am setting up a monitoring system and I want this monitoring system to send me emails when a problem with my servers occurs.

I have Postfix installed. And I want to use `mail`, `bsd-mailx` or `sendmail` (by Postfix) to send an email to `ivan@gmail.com` (for example).

I have an account at SendinBlue and I have configured my Postfix to use as a `relayhost` the SendinBlue SMTP server:

```
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = ec2-99-99-99-99.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com
mydomain = ec2-99-99-99-99.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = ec2-99-99-99-99.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com
mydestination = project-monitor-de-frankfurt, localhost.localdomain, localhost, ec2-99-99-99-99.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com
relayhost = smtp-relay.sendinblue.com:587
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
inet_interfaces = loopback-only
default_transport = error
relay_transport = error
inet_protocols = all

smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_sasl_mechanism_filter = plain, login
```

In `/var/log/mail.log` I always get `status=bounced (smtp-relay.sendinblue.com:587)` when I am trying to send mail through `sendmail ivan@gmail.com`. My `sasl_passwd` file is configured and `postmap`-ed.

I do not see a message like `Authentication Required` and in my SendinBlue account I see no statistics (0 bounced messages), which means that my mails do not go out of my Postfix MTA?

Is the domain can be a problem?

Why is this happening and how can I use SendinBlue or Mandrillapp (for example) to use them as a relay and send emails to `ivan@gmail.com`?

Comment: What's full bounce response?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's too little too late, but it might help someone else.

I had the same problem on Ubuntu 18.04 and it was resolved by putting a relay host in square brackets, and the port outside. Completly weird and never encountered this on other distributions. Might be something specific about postfix shipped with Ubuntu.

For example:

```
relayhost = [smtp-relay.sendinblue.com]:587
```

Comment: still getting errors but at least the connection time out/rejected error are gone now! thanks for sharing